# "MongoError: unknown operator: $id in loopback updateall

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, loopback, update-all

In my angular2 project i need to update multiple ids with same data.I have a function like this:

```
import { AgentApi } from '../../../../sdk/services/custom/Agent';
 @Injectable()
 export class AgentService {
  constructor(private agentApi: AgentApi) { }
   updateAgentShiftDetails(idArray, name) {
    var dataObj: any = {};
    dataObj.id = {
        'inq': idArray ------> id array contains ids like this:["590b095a0d271a0cb8e859sf", "590c63cee3adb75a19e84e56"]
    };
    return this.agentApi.updateAll({
        where: {
            'id': dataObj
        }
    }, {
            'name': name
        });
};
     }
```

in my responsebody i got an error like this:

```
Object {statusCode: 500, name: "MongoError", message: "unknown operator: $id", ok: 0, errmsg: "unknown operator: $id"…}
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How can i resolve this problem? am using loopback and mongodb.I am new to angular2. Any help will really appreciable.

Comment: Should it be  _id  ??

Comment: you mean  where: {
            '_ id': dataObj
        } like this? But still that issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid use of **where** here

```
import {
    AgentApi
} from '../../../../sdk/services/custom/Agent';
@Injectable()
export class AgentService {
    constructor(private agentApi: AgentApi) {}
    updateAgentShiftDetails(idArray, name) {
        var dataObj: any = {};
        dataObj.id = {
            'inq': idArray
        };
        return this.agentApi.updateAll(dataObj, {
            'name': name
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.
Why don't you use `$in`for this case?

```
this.agentApi.update( { _id: { $in: idArray } }, { name: name }, function (err, user) {

} )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found solution for my issue. there is no where clause for updateall that was the problem. I solved it. agentApi.updateAll(dataObj, {
                'name': name
            }); it works correctly  reference: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#where-clause-for-other-methods